# data is not been displayed from one file to another file in javascript using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

I have created two files index.js and image.js file.I am calling the image.js file in the index.js file.it is working but it is not displaying data in the json file.only the image variable name is getting displayed in my json file. Please help!!!

```js
image.js
const axios= require ('axios');
const cheerio=require('cheerio');
const request=require('request');

 async function imageNames() {
  const resp = await axios.get('https://www.google.com/');
  const $ = await cheerio.load(resp.data);
  let listImages = [];

  $('img').each((i, elem) => {
      listImages.push({
        name: $(elem).find('a').attr('href'),
        dom_data: $(elem).attr('')
      })
     
  });
  console.log(listImages);

}
module.exports={imageNames}

index.js
const request=require('request');
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fs = require("fs");
const image=require('./image');
const url = "https://www.google.com";
axios.get(url).then((res) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
const pageTitle = $("title").text();
 image.imageNames();
const contentJSON = {
    title: pageTitle.trim(),
    url:url.trim(),
    image:image 
};
const artFinal = JSON.stringify(contentJSON);
  const filename = pageTitle.slice(0, 9).trim() + ".json";
  fs.writeFileSync(filename, artFinal);
});

google.json file
{"title":"Google","url":"https://www.google.com","image":{}}
```

it is only displaying the variable in the image.js file data is not getting displayed on the console.I am saving it in a json format.

Comment: `const image = require('./image')` returns object, try this: `const {imageNames} = require('./image);` and than await that fn in callback: `axios.get().then(async () => { const image = await imageNames() })`. Also return stuff from `imageNames`

Comment: @Eggy Sorry can you  tell me in which file do i need to write the above code :axios.get().then(async () => { const image = await imageNames() })I am a noob and not able to follow the answer.It would be helpful if you could make the changes in my original two files and paste the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { imageNames } = require('./image');
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from `imageNames`. And also not using return value of that function, but module itself(which contains a function, and that why you get empty object from `JSON.stringify`). Try it yourself in console:

```js
JSON.stringify({ thisIsSomeFunction() {} }); // "{}"
```

Below is fixed code:

*image.js*

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

async function imageNames() {
  const resp = await axios.get('https://www.google.com/');
  const $ = await cheerio.load(resp.data);
  const listImages = [];

  $('img').each((i, elem) => {
      listImages.push({
        name: $(elem).find('a').attr('href'),
        dom_data: $(elem).attr('')
      })
     
  });
  
  // return data, otherwise functions will implicitly return `undefined`
  return listImages;
}

module.exports = {
  imageNames
}
```

*index.js*

```js
const request = require('request');
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fs = require("fs");
const { imageNames } = require('./image');

const url = "https://www.google.com";

// pass async function so you can `await` promises inside it
axios.get(url).then(async (res) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
  const pageTitle = $("title").text();

  // get data from function in *image.js*
  const image = await imageNames();
  const contentJSON = {
    title: pageTitle.trim(),
    url:url.trim(),
    // put returned data into an object
    image 
  };
  const artFinal = JSON.stringify(contentJSON);
  const filename = pageTitle.slice(0, 9).trim() + ".json";

  fs.writeFileSync(filename, artFinal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tow forms,

For many Functions or Methods in file;

```
const image =require('./image');

image.imageNames
```

Only one;

```
const { imageNames } = require('./image');

imageNames
```